# Slick.js slider on Shopify

Tags: jquery, slider, shopify, slick.js

I am struggling with Slick.js on Shopify.

I tested a slider on VisualCode on local server, and Slick works good.

But when I put the same code to Shopify, jQuery seems to not see this.

I've pasted all the CDN's and scripts.

The funny thing is, if I will paste the same Slick jQuery code on the Developer Tools > Console, then the Slick works.

This is simple code which works locally, but not on shopify:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js" integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.8.1/slick.min.js" integrity="sha512-XtmMtDEcNz2j7ekrtHvOVR4iwwaD6o/FUJe6+Zq+HgcCsk3kj4uSQQR8weQ2QVj1o0Pk6PwYLohm206ZzNfubg==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.8.1/slick.css" integrity="sha512-wR4oNhLBHf7smjy0K4oqzdWumd+r5/+6QO/vDda76MW5iug4PT7v86FoEkySIJft3XA0Ae6axhIvHrqwm793Nw==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.8.1/slick-theme.css" integrity="sha512-6lLUdeQ5uheMFbWm3CP271l14RsX1xtx+J5x2yeIDkkiBpeVTNhTqijME7GgRKKi6hCqovwCoBTlRBEC20M8Mg==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
    <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="slick/slick.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="slick/slick-theme.css"/> -->
</head>
<body>
    
    <div class="collection-slider">
        <div>your content</div>
        <div>your content</div>
        <div>your content</div>
        <div>your content</div>
        <div>your content</div>
        <div>your content</div>
        <div>your content</div>
        <div>your content</div>
        <div>your content</div>
        <div>your content</div>
        <div>your content</div>
        <div>your content</div>
        <div>your content</div>
        <div>your content</div>
        <div>your content</div>
      </div>
<style>
  .slick-prev, .slick-next{
    border: 2px solid green;

  }
    .collection-slider{
        width: 60%;
        margin: 0 auto;
        border: 1px solid black;
        background-color: gray;
    }
    .collection-slider div{
        margin: 5px;
        background-color: lightcyan;
        border:1px solid red;
    }
</style>
 <script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.collection-slider').slick({
  dots: false,
  infinite: false,
  speed: 300,
  slidesToShow: 4,
  slidesToScroll: 4,
  responsive: [
    {
      breakpoint: 1024,
      settings: {
        slidesToShow: 3,
        slidesToScroll: 3,
        infinite: true,
        dots: true
      }
    },
    {
      breakpoint: 600,
      settings: {
        slidesToShow: 2,
        slidesToScroll: 2
      }
    },
    {
      breakpoint: 480,
      settings: {
        slidesToShow: 1,
        slidesToScroll: 1
      }
    }
    // You can unslick at a given breakpoint now by adding:
    // settings: "unslick"
    // instead of a settings object
  ]
});
});                 
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Can I have any suggestions please?

I am working on 'Expanse' theme.

Thank you

Comment: Same code is working, you need to share the page URL to debug the code on live website

Comment: https://t1e3igr2nwqxzwzn-4368138340.shopifypreview.com

unfortunatelly its preview theme, so you would you like to go on any product page (just pick up one product) and over there you will see 'Customers also viewed' element. 
If you paste in the DevTools console this code : 
``
$('.collection-slider').slick()
```
you will see that this elements change to slider. 
The same code is not working from 'edit code' over the Shopify

Comment: Okay, thanks for sharing. your content is loaded using AJAX call and Shopify recommendation API. so when your code is running elements are not appended to the website. you need to check the element load and then add the JS code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to try the `setInterval` to run the code after some time and check for the HTML elements on the page, once the HTML elements are found clear the Interval using `clearInterval`
You also read more about these functions here [setInterval](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp), [clearInterval](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_clearinterval.asp)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var found = setInterval(function(){
        if( $(".collection-slider").length ){
            clearInterval(found);
        }
        // slick slider code
        $(".collection-slider").slick({
            dots: !1,
            infinite: !1,
            speed: 300,
            slidesToShow: 4,
            slidesToScroll: 4,
            responsive: [{
                    breakpoint: 1024,
                    settings: {
                        slidesToShow: 3,
                        slidesToScroll: 3,
                        infinite: !0,
                        dots: !0
                    }
                }, {
                    breakpoint: 600,
                    settings: {
                        slidesToShow: 2,
                        slidesToScroll: 2
                    }
                }, {
                    breakpoint: 480,
                    settings: {
                        slidesToShow: 1,
                        slidesToScroll: 1
                    }
                }
            ]
        })
        
    }, 200);
});
```